# Automatically capitalizing: 'ithing' and 'Ithing' to 'iThing'

Tags: feature-request, editing

When I'm editing a post, one of the most common things that I end up doing* is fixing the capitalization of the names Apple's products, like in this question's title.

**How would people feel about automatically changing all instances of 'iname' or 'Iname' to 'iName'?

I don't imagine that SE has this functionality built in, so consider this a feature request.**

*I don't feel compelled to edit posts *just* to fix product name capitalization, but I do it if I'm in the neighborhood/

Comment: iNteresting but possibly iRritating

Comment: And here I was hoping Apple would get tired sooner than later of their iProduct names...

Comment: It's a brand. They won't drop this entity until John Sculley takes over Apple again.

Answer (score 3):

I think in the short term, a userscript would be wonderful for this.

And in the long term, it's a great customization for the site, perhaps even the network as a whole. And it's really just a fixed set of strings.

iMac, iPhone, iPod, iPad, MacMini, MacPro, Mac OSX, and ummm, a few more :). The latter half of those are less "Special" than the iSeries are.

Comment: Actually, the s in Xserve is lowercase. See Apple's page: http://www.apple.com/support/xserve/

Comment: Well imagine that. A name that conforms to standard english rules...

Answer (score 1):

#### Mac:

- iMac
- Mac mini
- Mac Pro
- MacBook
- MacBook Pro
- MacBook Air

#### iPod, iPhone, and iPad

- iPhone
- iPhone 3G
- iPhone 3GS
- iPhone 4
- iPod
- iPod shuffle
- iPod nano
- iPod classic
- iPod touch
- iPad
- iPad 2

#### Misc

- AirPort Express
- AirPort Extreme
- Apple TV

#### Software:

- Mac OS X *or* OS X
- iLife
- iMovie
- iPhoto
- iTunes
- iChat
- iDVD
- FaceTime
- GarageBand
- iCal
- QuickTime
- TextEdit
- Xcode

Comment: Does Xcode really need to be auto-cap'ed? I mean, it's a noun with a capital first letter, and lowercase rest.

Comment: Yes, it does. Not for reasons of uppercase, but for reasons of lowercase. XCode -> Xcode. Right... should have realized that.

Comment: you forgot the iMac ;)